# How to get the url to Google doc image

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I have a Google Docs document which contains one image. I found images's `objectId` as stated here https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/InlineObject but I can't understand how to get an url to that image. 
I tried searching for this `objectId` in Drive but it returns *File not found*.

Any ideas ?

[image: do]

**Update**

As noted by @Tanaike the image info is contained in the `result.inlineObjects` and 
not directly in the paragraph.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the URL of the inserted image in Google Document using Google Docs API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

I think that the property of `inlineObjectElement` that you are checking is in the paragraph. The information of the inserted images can be seen at the property of `inlineObjects`. And the URL can be seen at the property of `ImageProperties`.

The endpoint is as follows.

#### Endpoint:

```
GET https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/{documentId}?fields=inlineObjects
```

- Here, as a sample, `inlineObjects` is used as `fields`. You can also use `*` as `fields`.

#### Result:

The URL can be retrieved as follows. It supposes that `response` is the returned value from above endpoint.

```
url = response.inlineObjects["kix.###"].inlineObjectProperties.embeddedObject.imageProperties.sourceUri
```

- `kix.###` is `inlineObjectId` in your question.
- If the image is inserted from the URL of outside, the URL is the same with the URL which was used when the image was inserted.
- If the image is inserted from Google Drive, the URL is like below.

  - `https://lh3.google.com/u/0/d/{fileId}=w###-h###`
  - In this case, `{fileId}` is the file ID of the image. You can retrieve the original file using this file ID.

#### References:

- [Method: documents.get](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get)
- [InlineObject](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/InlineObject)
- [ImageProperties](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/EmbeddedObject#ImageProperties)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 5):

**Step #1**: Right-click and Copy the image from the Google Doc.
**Step #2**: Paste into **dynalist.io**.

(**Note**: Dynalist doesn't allow you to paste images, but you can paste images from Google Docs because it just adds the link.)

I understand that this may not help if you are trying to do something with the API, but for finding the link to a single image, it is the simplest method I've found.

Answer (score 0):

use the drive and doc api

1. use the gdoc api retrieve the [ContentUri:](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/docs/v1#ImageProperties)

(Document.InlineObjects[imageid].InlineObjectProperties.EmbeddedObject.ImageProperties.ContentUri)

```
imageid has the form "kix.###..."

The imageid can be retrieved frm the InlineObjects map, the key is the imageid
```

2. After obtaining the ContentUri you must strip the ending "=wxx-hyy" to obtain the the image file id for the drive api
3. use the drive api to obtain the file pointer:

   *fil, err = service.Files.Get(fileid).Do()
4. After obtaining the file pointer, you can retrieve the image file characteristics (see [File](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api@v0.70.0/drive/v3#File))
5. Alternatively the image file can be [downloaded via](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api@v0.70.0/drive/v3#FilesService):

   httpResp, err =service.Files.Export(fileid, mime).Download()
6. mime types are listed [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/mime-types)

Comment: 1.  the gdoc api has two URIs: ContentUri and SourceUri. ContentUri is a link to the actual image used in the document (usually that image has reduced pixels) while SourceUri is a link to the original image

Comment: 2. Number 5 is incorrect. The Export method only works with google documents. The correct answer is to use service.Files.Get(filid).Download().

Comment: 3. Alternatively one can use http.get(uri) using the net/http package.