# How to extract or read Image from Google Doc using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, google-api, google-docs

I am trying to read data from my google docs. So I am using python right now and I have implemented the [Google Docs AP](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/python)I and using python. I just copy pasted the code there provided by google and made some modifications and I successfully read the data **LINE BY LINE** but the **TEXT ONLY**!  Now I am trying something new and have inserted an image. Here is what it looks like.

[image: Image of my google doc content]

[Google Doc Link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ckNmcbdRCryTqLVmw9iHDVil6Lfl6rhX_x7KayDZpm4/edit?usp=sharing)

Very simple right... It has there a bulletpoint and sub bulletpoints containing an image and a "Hello" text. Now when I read the data (it reads it line by line) I tried printing out what the API returns and it returns  a `dictionary` containing `dictionaries` again. Here is what it looks like.

```
{'startIndex': 1, 'endIndex': 41, 'paragraph': {'elements': [{'startIndex': 1, 'endIndex': 41, 'textRun': {'content': 'This is the Python Programming Language\n', 'textStyle': {}}}], 'paragraphStyle': {'namedStyleType': 'NORMAL_TEXT', 'direction': 'LEFT_TO_RIGHT', 'indentFirstLine': {'magnitude': 18, 'unit': 'PT'}, 'indentStart': {'magnitude': 36, 'unit': 'PT'}}, 'bullet': {'listId': 'kix.y7w314ij0ywy', 'textStyle': {'underline': False}}}}


{'startIndex': 41, 'endIndex': 43, 'paragraph': {'elements': [{'startIndex': 41, 'endIndex': 42, 'inlineObjectElement': {'inlineObjectId': 'kix.o4cuh6wash2n', 'textStyle': {}}}, {'startIndex': 42, 'endIndex': 43, 'textRun': {'content': '\n', 'textStyle': {}}}], 'paragraphStyle': {'namedStyleType': 'NORMAL_TEXT', 'direction': 'LEFT_TO_RIGHT', 'indentFirstLine': {'magnitude': 54, 'unit': 'PT'}, 'indentStart': {'magnitude': 72, 'unit': 'PT'}}, 'bullet': {'listId': 'kix.y7w314ij0ywy', 'nestingLevel': 1, 'textStyle': {'underline': False}}}}


{'startIndex': 43, 'endIndex': 49, 'paragraph': {'elements': [{'startIndex': 43, 'endIndex': 49, 'textRun': {'content': 'Hello\n', 'textStyle': {}}}], 'paragraphStyle': {'namedStyleType': 'NORMAL_TEXT', 'direction': 'LEFT_TO_RIGHT', 'indentFirstLine': {'magnitude': 54, 'unit': 'PT'}, 'indentStart': {'magnitude': 72, 'unit': 'PT'}}, 'bullet': {'listId': 'kix.y7w314ij0ywy', 'nestingLevel': 1, 'textStyle': {'underline': False}}}}
```

As you can see there , there are 3 dictionaries containing their `key` and `value` pairs. Take note that those three are for every line from the document. As you can also observe there is the key `content` and its `value`(s) are the text from the document.

If you look at the nested dictionaries it is these ones:

```
{'content': 'This is the Python Programming Language\n', 'textStyle': {}}
{'content': '\n', 'textStyle': {}}
{'content': 'Hello\n', 'textStyle': {}}
```

Now what I've noticed is it returned a `\n` for the line where the image contains. Also I've looked for at least it could have probably have a `key` and its value would be a temporary url for the image however it doesn't seem to have that. So my question is  there a way to somehow read this image (also EXTRACT IT) using this API that I am using? Probably I am just missing something out... Can someone help me with this? Any other alternative solution would be very much appreciated! Thank you!

By the way here is the source code provided by google and I have made modifications on the `read_strucutural_elements` function on how it would read the data for my personal purpose but there as you can see that's how it works where the API returns a dictionary for every line data. I've also noticed that the API somehow really does read it line by line and returns a `dictionary` of it

```
def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Docs API.
    Prints the title of a sample document.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('docs', 'v1', credentials=creds)

    # Retrieve the documents contents from the Docs service.
    document = service.documents().get(documentId=DOCUMENT_ID).execute()

    #print('The title of the document is: {}'.format(document.get('title')))
    data = read_strucutural_elements(document.get("body").get("content"))
```

Here is the `read_strucutural_elements` function and I just print out there the elements from the `elements` parameter, where that parameter contains those data line by line.

```
def read_strucutural_elements(elements):

    for value in elements:
        print(value) #the value of the value variable is the nested dictionaries I've shown above
        print()
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: welcome to SO! maybe you could provide a link to a publicly shared google doc instead of the image.

Comment: Hello! Okay sure! just a sec

Comment: Done! :) I have added the link sample doc.

Comment: ok, good, now people can test code directly on that. Note that the link goes through facebook before reaching google docs, you might want to avoid the redirect...

Comment: Done :) Thank you!  I changed it from the link of the shared link itself. I hope you guys can help me. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the url to Google doc image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57560633/how-to-get-the-url-to-google-doc-image)

Comment: Hello! The link provided is the answer I am looking for, however the problem or conflict I am having is different from the one on the link. So I am thinking that this shouldn't be "DUPLICATED" for other people that might have the same problem as mine... probably they might encounter this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking at the dictionary output, the image is a inlineObject with a specific id. you should be able to retrieve the image using its url. to get the url, see related question: [How to get the url to Google doc image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57560633/how-to-get-the-url-to-google-doc-image)

Comment: Thanks, I got it going and yep it does answer my question with the link you provided however my problem was different compared to the one asking there. But yes  that's the same solution too! Thanks